# When you get teamkills in B02 do you lose your score streak?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2

When you're playing hardcore and your teammate kills you, do you lose your score-streak or not? Also do you lose your progress to a bloodthirsty or merciless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, and yes.

When you get a "team kill", by killing a friendly, any progress toward kill streak is reverted back to 0, and you are awarded a -1 to the total kill count/points counter (-100 points I believe?).